Can every graph of clique number k be partitioned into (at most) k independent graphs?
I came across the claim as a sub problem. I ask if it is always achievable because the minimum number of independent sets will have to be at least k, as otherwise some two vertices from the same clique will end up together.
Is it too good to be true? Or maybe it's not?

Consider cycle graphs.

A partitioning of a graph $G$ into $l$ indepdendent sets is called an $l$-coloring. The smallest $l$ such that $G$ has an $l$-coloring is called the chromatic number of $G$, and is denoted $\chi(G)$. So your question is asking whether $G$ having clique number $k$ guarantees $\chi(G)\leq k$. The answer is no, and a simple example of a class of graphs that have clique number $2$ but are not $2$-colorable is the class of odd cycles.
More interestingly, a famous result of Erdős states that there are graphs with arbitrarily large chromatic number and arbitrarily large length of a shortest cycle. Since complete graphs on at least three vertices have cycles of length $3$, this implies that in particular there is no integer $i$ such that all graphs with clique number $2$ can be partitioned into $i$ independent sets. In other words there are graphs of clique number $2$ and arbitrarily large chromatic number.

Yes this is crystal clear. Thank you for the answer.

I don't have enough rep to upvote, but thanks.
